# Why does this code behave inconsistently?

Tags: c, gcc, assert

I'm trying to implement the generic stack illustrated in lectures 5 and 6 in CS107 - Programming Paradigms (online course at Stanford). 
The following code, representing an example presented in the lectures, compiles, but doesn't seem to behave consistently since I often get an assertion failure.

I've noticed the behavior in Geany and gcc (`$ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18) 6.3.0 20170516`), but not on `[https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.phphttp://)' so I wonder if it is caused by something in gcc or a bug I don't seem to see now.

Code:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct {
    void *elems;
    int elemSize;
    int logLen;
    int allocLen;

} stack;

void StackNew(stack *s, int elemSize);
void StackDispose(stack *s);
void StackPush(stack *s, void *elemAddr);
void StackPop(stack *s, void * elemAddr);

void StackNew(stack *s, int elemSize)
{
        assert(s->elemSize > 0);
        s->elemSize = elemSize;
        s->logLen = 0;
        s->allocLen = 4;
        s->elems = malloc(4 * elemSize);
        assert(s->elems != NULL);
}

void StackDispose(stack *s)
{
    free(s->elems);
}

static void StackGrow(stack *s)
{
    s->allocLen *= 2;
    s->elems = realloc(s->elems, s->allocLen * s->elemSize);
}

void StackPush(stack *s, void *elemAddr)
{
    if(s->logLen == s->allocLen)
    StackGrow(s);
    void *target = (char *) s->elems + s->logLen * s->elemSize;
    memcpy(target, elemAddr, s->elemSize);
    s->logLen++;
}

void StackPop(stack *s, void *elemAddr)
{
    void *source = (char *) s->elems +
            (s->logLen - 1) * s->elemSize;
    memcpy(elemAddr, source, s->elemSize);
    s->logLen--;
}


int main(void)
{
  const char *friends[] = {"Al", "Bob", "Carl"};

  stack stringStack;
  StackNew(&stringStack, sizeof(char *));
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      char *copy = strdup(friends[i]);
      StackPush(&stringStack, &copy);
  }

  char *name;

  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    StackPop(&stringStack, &name);
    printf("%s\n", name);
    free(name);
  }
  StackDispose(&stringStack);
  return 0;

}
```

Sample output for several consecutive executions without any source modifications:

```
$ ./stack4
stack4: stack4.c:21: StackNew: Assertion 's->elemSize' > 0 failed.
Aborted
$ ./stack4
stack4: stack4.c:21: StackNew: Assertion 's->elemSize' > 0' failed.
Aborted
$ ./stack4
Carl
Bob
Al
$ ./stack4
Carl
Bob
Al
$ ./stack4
Carl
Bob
Al
$ ./stack4
stack4: stack4.c:21: StackNew: Assertion 's->elemSize' > 0' failed.
Aborted
$ ./stack4
stack4: stack4.c:21: StackNew: Assertion 's->elemSize' > 0 failed.
Aborted
$ ./stack4
Carl
Bob
Al
$ ./stack4
stack4: stack4.c:21: StackNew: Assertion 's->elemSize' > 0' failed.
```

Comment: I do not think `StackNew(&stringStack, sizeof(char **));` is correct.  `sizeof(char **)` should be the size of an element.  In this code's case that is  `char *`.  Typically those different pointer types have the same size

Comment: A robust _generic stack_ would use `size_t`, rather than `int` for size calculations and `elemSize`.

Comment: The `sizeof(char *)` is a mistake on my side, I've corrected it in the question (was playing a bit with the code and missed it when posting the question). Thank you for mentioning `size_t` for a better generic implementation. The lecture started with a stack of integers, then that version was gradually modified to be more and more generic, hopefully in the end it will turn into o a robust implementation.

Comment: Tip: With `friends[]`, ignore its type for the moment.  `friends` is an array.  Rather than `StackNew(&stringStack, sizeof(char *));`, no need to code the type of the array element, instead code the array element: `StackNew(&stringStack, sizeof friend[0]);`  This is correct for code regardless of the type of `friends[]`.

Comment: That's interesting. Why doesn't the type matter? What resource would you recommend to learn more about this, if I may ask? And thank you for the interest in my learning and trivial question.

Comment: Type does not matter as this code saves data via `StackPush(stack *s, void *elemAddr)` that is explicitly attempting to ignore the type.  The initialization routine `StackNew(stack *s, int elemSize)` only needs the _size_ of an element, not the _type_.  `sizeof friend[0]` provides a direct calculation of the size of an element.  `sizeof(some_type)`  works *if* the correct type was used - which was potentially wrong with  `StackNew(&stringStack, sizeof(char **));`  [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/) is a good resource.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're checking `s->elemSize` before setting it. You're using an uninitialized variable.

Fix: Either `assert(elemSize > 0)` (check the function parameter, not the member of `s`), or do the `assert` after the `s->elemSize = elemSize` assignment.